# Create open close delimiters in XML created with Excel

Tags: xml, excel

I'm exporting an XML file from excel, and for empty elements, excel creates the field like this:

```
<my_empty_element/>
```

However, my application needs it to be like this:

```
<my_empty_element></my_empty_element>
```

Is there any way to have excel to do this, I'm trying to avoid workarounds like search/replace text on the XMl file?

Comment: Also, how are you parsing the file? Most SAX/DOM parsing libraries should be able to handle this case. If you wrote your own parser you may want to add support for this fairly common case or use an established XML parsing library.

Comment: I'm using this function ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("CertificadoEnergetico_Map").Export in my vba code

Comment: To edit, the XML after exported, I'm using MSXML2.DOMDocument to load the XML and insert some data on elements I cannot map in the excel sheet. I believe this is the parsing library, on references I have "Microsoft XML, v3.0"

Comment: like others have said - from XML / DOM parsing perspective it makes no difference how the empty element is encoded - in fact it's quite correct for excel to export like this.

Comment: If you're later parsing this with MS tools it should handle such elements like any other - for example you can append children elements to such empty elements and will show up correctly when you serialize again to text/XML

Comment: Correcting my post to avoid misinterpretation, the problem exists because the application/service which receives the XML doesn't accept the empty element encoded on the single open/close "/>". Probably a poor XML implementation, but it's a public service not under my control, so I'll have to do it like that anyway.. guess I'll end up doing the find/replace.

Answer (score 0):

*Why* does your application need it to be that way?

Instead of fixing Excel's correct behavior, why not fix the application that doesn't understand sole-tags?